# Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I have been reading a research paper called "Extracting human expertise for constructing knowledge spaces an algorithm", and they provided a way on how to choose the best question to provide to the user of the website. So for every we question I have on my database it has the corresponding information " Number of inferences for a potential No answer" and "Number of potential inferences for a YES answer", since every question will be answered either by YES or NO. Now to choose the best question to display based on that information the paper provided the following

"For each candidate question we consider the number of inferences for a positive answer and that for a negative answer, and we select the questions for which the minimum of these two numbers is maximal over all questions. From these, a best question is picked as one for which the total number of inferences-or, equivalently, the "other" number—is maximal."

I find this sentence is illogical because if there is a question in which the minimum of these two numbers is maximal over all questions it would be only " ONE QUESTION" not questions as stated by the paper. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be several questions with the same maximal minimum?

Comment: What if there is a tie?

Comment: @Gribouillis because if there is a question which the minimum of these two numbers is maximal over all questions, atumotaically the other answer will maximum in that question. so for example let's say the potential Nos are the maximum over all question and minimum to the potential YES in that question, then that automatically will make the YES in that question a maximum. so there will be only one question .

Comment: @mjw I didn't get your question, fully

Comment: What if the number of inferences for two different documents is the same.  Then, there is not one minumum but two.  Now, if the "other" number is the same, we have a tie.  Both documents are maximal of minimum (or whatever it is).  The point is there may be more than one maximum (or minimum).

Comment: @mjw Yes, I thought of this point, but I neglected it, because i said otherwise they would have mentioned "may" in the research paper, but I agree with your point, and probably that's what it means since it is logical.